# Showing that the sum of any 1-cycle and its opposite orientation is a 1-boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Suppose that $\phi$ is a $1-cycle$ in a topological space $X$, and that $\phi^*:= \phi r$ is its opposite orientation where $r(t,1-t)=r(1-t,t)$. How should one show that there is a $2-chain$ whose boundary is $\phi+\phi^*$?

I know a proof for a more general fact (given any 1-simplex, the sum of it and its opposite orientation is a 1-boundary), but for this simple case is there any simple solution?

Comment: I think you need more information about  $X$ If you mean a loop  homotopic to its inverse, there may not be any, for example if $X= S^1$, there are no such loops.

Comment: Well, other than any loop homotopic to the constant loop.

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojevic: indeed.

Comment: I didn’t talk about homotopy, it’s about homology

Comment: If a cycle and its inverse are not homotopic, there isn't much you can say about them except that they are simplices: $\Delta_1\to X$. If they are homotopic, then you can use the homotopy $H$ to produce a simplex $\sigma:\Delta_2\to X.\ \sigma $ is obtained in the following way: take $I\times I$ and define a quotient map $q$ that collapses the square to a triangle. Then, $H$ factors through the quotient as $H=\sigma\circ q$, and then $\partial \sigma =\phi+\phi^*.$ It's a good exercise to fill in the details. So,bottom line; without more information, your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that you are asking about the singular chain complex of $X$, so in this answer a "simplex" means a "singular simplex in the topological space $X$".

Suppose at first that one knows how to find a solution for each 1-simplex $\sigma$, i.e. one knows how to find $\tau$ so that $\partial\tau = \sigma + \sigma^*$.

Consider any $1$-chain $\phi$ (not just a 1-cycle). We may write $\phi$ as a finite linear combination of 1-simplices,
$$\phi = \sum_i a_i \sigma_i
$$
where each $\sigma_i$ is a 1-simplex and each $a_i$ is a coefficient. Using your proof for a 1-simplex, it follows that for each $i$ there is a 2-chain $\tau_i$ such that $\partial \tau_i = \sigma_i + \sigma^*_i$. From this we obtain
$$\phi + \phi^* = \sum_i a_i \sigma_i + \sum_i a_i \sigma^*_i = \sum_i a_i (\sigma_i + \sigma^*_i) = \partial \left( \sum_i a_i \tau_i \right)
$$
and so $\sum_i a_i \tau_i$ is the required 2-chain.

So to complete the answer, I'll describe $\tau$ in the special case of a single 1-simplex $\sigma$ (which does not have to be a cycle). I'll follow the standard notations in many algebraic topology books, for example Hatcher's book. By definition, $\sigma$ is a continuous function $\sigma : \Delta^1 \to X$. Let $c : \Delta^2 \to \Delta^1$ be the affine map that maps the first and third vertices of $\Delta^2$ to the first vertex of $\Delta^1$, and maps the second vertex of $\Delta^2$ to the second vertex of $\Delta^1$. Let $d : \Delta^2 \to \Delta^1$ be the constant map which take $\Delta^2$ to the first vertex of $\Delta^1$. Then we just take $\tau = \sigma \circ c + \sigma \circ d$. A short computation shows that $\partial \tau = \sigma + \sigma^*$.

Comment: Thanks, However I wanted to know if there is an easy solution independent of the general fact that you used in the answer

Comment: Your use of the term "general" is unclear to me. The "1-simplex" statement is a special case of the "1-chain" statement, not a general case. Namely, it is the special case where the sum $\phi = \sum_i a_i \sigma_i$ has only one term, and the coefficient of that term is $a_i=1$.

Comment: I mean forget about chains and consider a simplex which is itself a cycle. Is there any routine solution in this case?

Comment: Okay, I thought that was the case you said you could do, but I added a description anyway.

Comment: Thank you, now it is exactly what I wanted